# GAE Datastore ndb models accessed in 5 different ways

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I run an online marketplace. I don't know the best way to access NDB models. I'm afraid it's a real mess and I really don't know which way to turn. If you don't have time for a full response, I'm happy to read an article on NDB best practices

I have these classes, which are interlinked in different ways:

- `User(webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User)` controls seller logins
- `Partner(ndb.Model)` contains information about sellers
- `menuitem(ndb.Model)` contains information about items on menu
- `order(ndb.Model)` contains buyer information & information about an order (all purchases are "guest" purchases)
- `Preapproval(ndb.Model)` contains payment information saved from PayPal

**How they're linked.**

**`User` - `Partner`**

A 1-to-1 relationship. Both have "email address" fields. If these match, then can retrieve user from partner or vice versa. For example:

```
 user = self.user
 partner = model.Partner.get_by_email(user.email_address)
```

Where in the Partner model we have:

```
 @classmethod
 def get_by_email(cls, partner_email):
    query = cls.query(Partner.email == partner_email)
    return query.fetch(1)[0]
```

**`Partner` - `menuitem`**

`menuitem`s are children of `Partner`. Created like so:

```
myItem = model.menuitem(parent=model.partner_key(partner_name))
```

menuitems are referenced like this:

`menuitems = model.menuitem.get_by_partner_name(partner.name)`

where `get_by_partner_name` is this:

```
 @classmethod
 def get_by_partner_name(cls, partner_name):
   query = cls.query(
      ancestor=partner_key(partner_name)).order(ndb.GenericProperty("itemid"))
   return query.fetch(300)
```

and where `partner_key()` is a function just floating at the top of the `model.py` file:
    def partner_key(partner_name=DEFAULT_PARTNER_NAME):
      return ndb.Key('Partner', partner_name)

**`Partner` - `order`**

Each `Partner` can have many `order`s. `order` has a parent that is `Partner`. How an order is created:

```
    partner_name = self.request.get('partner_name')
    partner_k = model.partner_key(partner_name)
    myOrder = model.order(parent=partner_k)
```

How an order is referenced:

```
myOrder_k = ndb.Key('Partner', partnername, 'order', ordernumber)
myOrder = myOrder_k.get()
```

and sometimes like so:
    order = model.order.get_by_name_id(partner.name, ordernumber)

(where in `model.order` we have:
    @classmethod
    def get_by_name_id(cls, partner_name, id):
    return ndb.Key('Partner', partner_name, 'order', int(id)).get()
)

*This doesn't feel particularly efficient, particularly as I often have to look up the partner in the datastore just to pull up an order. For example:*

```
user = self.user
partner = model.Partner.get_by_email(user.email_address)
order = model.order.get_by_name_id(partner.name, ordernumber)
```

*Have tried desperately to get something simple like `myOrder = order.get_by_id(ordernumber)` to work, but it seems that having a partner parent stops that working.*

**`Preapproval` - `order`.**

a 1-to-1 relationship. Each order can have a 'Preapproval'. Linkage: a field in the Preapproval class: `order = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=order)`.

creating a Preapproval:

```
item = model.Preapproval( order=myOrder.key, ...)
```

accessing a Preapproval:

```
preapproval = model.Preapproval.query(model.Preapproval.order == order.key).get()
```

This seems like the easiest method to me.

TL;DR: I'm linking & accessing models in many ways, and it's not very systematic.

Comment: Here is a rather general article about GAE Datastore best practices related to your question, written by one of the largest users of App Engine: http://bjk5.com/post/54202245691/the-app-engine-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### User - Parner

You could replace:

```
 @classmethod
 def get_by_email(cls, partner_email):
    query = cls.query(Partner.email == partner_email)
    return query.fetch(1)[0]
```

with:

```
 @classmethod
 def get_by_email(cls, partner_email):
    query = cls.query(Partner.email == partner_email).get()
```

But because of transactions issues is better to use entity groups: User should be parent of Partner.

In this case instead of using get_by_email you can get user without queries:

```
user = partner.key.parent().get()
```

Or do an ancestor query for getting the partner object:

```
partner = Partner.query(ancestor=user_key).get()
```

### Query

Don't use fetch() if you don't need it. Use queries as iterators.
Instead of:

```
return query.fetch(300)
```

just:

```
return query
```

And then use query as:

```
for something in query:
    blah
```

### Relationships: Partner-Menu Item and Partner - Order

Why are you using entity groups? Ancestors are not used for modeling 1 to N relationships (necessarily). Ancestors are used for transactions, defining entity groups. They are useful in composition relationships (e.g.: partner - user)

You can use a KeyProperty for the relationship. (multivalue (i.e. repeated=true) or not, depending on the orientation of the relationship)

> Have tried desperately to get something simple like myOrder = order.get_by_id(ordernumber) to work, but it seems that having a partner parent stops that working.

No problem if you stop using ancestors in this relationship.

---

> TL;DR: I'm linking & accessing models in many ways, and it's not very systematic

There is not a systematic way of linking models. It depends of many factors: cardinality, number of possible items in each side, need transactions, composition relationship, indexes, complexity of future queries, denormalization for optimization, etc.

Comment: Thank you Hernán. Interesting that there isn't a system. I wish there was an "If This Then That" guide to linking models in the ndb.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the first step in cleaning this up is as follows:

At the top of your .py file, import all your models, so you don't have to keep using `model.ModelName`.  That cleans up a bit if the code.  `model.ModelName` becomes `ModelName`.

First best practice in cleaning this up is to always use a capital letter as the first letter to name a class.  A model name is a class.  Above, you have mixed model names, like Partner, order, menuitem.  It makes it hard to follow. Plus, when you use `order` as a model name, you may end up with conflicts.  Above you redefined `order` as a variable twice.  Use `Order` as the model name, and `this_order` as the lookup, and `order_key` as the key, to clear up some conflicts.

Ok, let's start there